# correlation between dependent variable and instrument

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, instrumental-variables, dependent-variable, wald-test

I have an additional question to the issue of correlation between dependent variables and instruments - which i have some problems understanding. I'm estimating a model by IV due to endogeneity in a independent variable but here is the problem: from the first stage my instrument is clearly significant on a 5 pct. level (p-value 0.037) but when i do a correlation test between the dependent variable and the instrument, this is even more significant (p-value 0.020) which concerns me a lot. The wald F test in the iv reggresion shows a highly strong instrument (F statistic 39.02) - i'm fully aware of the possibility of the indirect effect of the independent variable but im concerned about the significance - thank you from denmark!!!!!!!!

sorry in advance for my limited brain capacity...